# busybox sh shell doesn't know any command

Tags: docker, sh, busybox, portainer

As a summary:
No commands exist in Busybox "sh" in a Portainer Docker container.

Nuances, as always:

There is a Portainer tool image I'd like to have shell access in.
Why I need shell access there? It's because I'd like to discover the ability to connect more than one docker context (other than default)
via additional docker socket file mapping.

Portainer developers take some steps (they say for security reasons) to disable the ablity to get an interactive console inside the running container - there are no `bin/bash`, `bin/sh` etc.

I've downloaded Busybox from
https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.35.0-x86_64-linux-musl/busybox

and created my own debug container based on th  original Portainer one:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.3
LABEL destiny="Portainer debug"

ADD busybox busybox
ENTRYPOINT [""]
CMD [""]
```

Executed image build command:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t portainer_debug:latest .
```

... and started a container with it:

```
docker run --name ppp -it portainer_debug /busybox sh
```

I entered into a shell inside of the running container.
Unfortunately, I found that there are no commands available.
For example, `ls` command returns:

```
/ # ls
sh: ls: not found
/ #
```

It also means that Busybox commands (`sh` above) work as a parameter at container start. I checked it with "ls" as a paramater:

```
$ docker run --name ppp -it portainer_debug /busybox ls
busybox         docker-compose  kubectl         sys
data            etc             portainer       tmp
dev             helm            proc
docker          kompose         public
$
```

Note: "exit" command works inside "sh".

The same excercise with alpine image works as expected:

```
/ # ls
bin      busybox  dev      etc      home     lib      media    mnt      opt      proc     root     run      sbin     srv      sys      tmp      usr      var
/ #
```

I'd be glad and very thankful if somebody could suggest the next steps to understand why busybox "forgets" all commands.

Answer (score 4):

From https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html :

> USAGE
>
> BusyBox is a multi-call binary. A multi-call binary is an executable
> program that performs the same job as more than one utility program.
> That means there is just a single BusyBox binary, but that single
> binary acts like a large number of utilities. This allows BusyBox to
> be smaller since all the built-in utility programs (we call them
> applets) can share code for many common operations.
>
> You can also invoke BusyBox by issuing a command as an argument on the
> command line. For example, entering
>
> ```
>     /bin/busybox ls
> ```
>
> will also cause BusyBox to behave as 'ls'.
>
> Of course, adding '/bin/busybox' into every command would be painful.
> So most people will invoke BusyBox using links to the BusyBox binary.
>
> For example, entering
>
> ```
>     ln -s /bin/busybox ls
>     ./ls
> ```
>
> will cause BusyBox to behave as 'ls' (if the 'ls' command has been
> compiled into BusyBox). Generally speaking, you should never need to
> make all these links yourself, as the BusyBox build system will do
> this for you when you run the 'make install' command.
>
> If you invoke BusyBox with no arguments, it will provide you with a
> list of the applets that have been compiled into your BusyBox binary.

You only copied the binary `busybox` into the image. You can do `./busybox ls` or create the symlink, and add the directory with symlinks to `$PATH` if you want shell to find them.

> why busybox "forget" all commands.

Busybox didn't "forget" anything, it is inanimate, *you* just haven't correctly used.

---

For example, below I do:

- Execute portainer docker image.
- Because I am lazy, I do not write a `Dockerfile`, I just mount busybox executable that I have installed on my host to inside the docker container. It's the same as COPY in container.
- The docker container executes a `/busybox sh` shell

  - `-c` which executes a script
  - the script creates the directory `/busybox mkdir /bin`
  - the script for each tool from busybox - `for i in $(/busybox list)`

    - creates a symlink to busybox executable inside `/bin` directory - `/busybox ln -s /busybox /bin/$i`
  - the above two steps are exactly as explained in Busybox faq https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#getting_started
  - then the script executes an interactive shell to interact with me

Because `/bin` is by default in PATH, after creating the directory and symlinks, all Busybox tools are available. Note that all commands are prepended with `/busybox` to facilitate the Busybox invoking explained in the documentation above, before the creation of directory in PATH with symlinks.

```
$ docker run -ti --rm --entrypoint '' -v /bin/busybox:/busybox:ro portainer/portainer-ce:2.9.3 /busybox sh -c '/busybox mkdir /bin; for i in $(/busybox --list); do /busybox ln -s /busybox /bin/$i; done; sh -li'
/ # ls
bin             data            docker          etc             kompose         portainer       public          tmp
busybox         dev             docker-compose  helm            kubectl         proc            sys
/ # echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: The [BusyBox FAQ](https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#getting_started) has a slightly more complete recipe for setting up all of the symlinks.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk for the answer!
The "forget" usage is figurative here. The point is that busybox works fine if I use commands as arguments, but sh behave different for portainer and alpine images.
In case of portainer interactive sh can't find and execure any commands (there is ls as example). At the same time interactive sh for alpine-based busybox invocation runs busybox commands normally (ls execution results privided above also).

Comment: Alpine image just has the directory with symlinks to busybox created in /bin .

Comment: @KamiCuk I doubt that alpine has any default symlinks to busybox in / directory, especially if busybox executable is added later. You can find that if busybox added as busyboxx, it works well also. Moreover, symlinks idea contradicts with busybox concept to have single independent executable with embedded commands.

Comment: I do not understand. The `alpine` linux distribution has symlinks to `busybox` inside `/bin` directory, `$ docker run -ti --rm alpine ls -la /bin | head -n 20` `arch -> /bin/busybox` `ash -> /bin/busybox` etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk You're talking about busybox inside /bin directory, but my issue is that I've copied busybox into portainer (and into alpine) image at root (/) directory. sh shell ay alpine-based container withbusybox at root directory works fine, but sh shell at portainer-based container with the same buseybox executable at the same root directory can't find commands. I assume some specific at portainer containr that affect busybox this way and my goal is to discover this specific.

Comment: The location of busybox executable is not relevant. What is relevant, is the existence of a directory filled with hundreds of symlinks to busybox executable and the environment variable `PATH` with that directory. You can move the busybox executable, adjust the symlinks, and it will be fine. There is nothing specific with portainer container, it just doesn't have the directory filled with symlinks added to PATH.

Comment: I still fail to understand your concerns. `sh shell at portainer-based container with the same buseybox executable at the same root directory can't find commands` I believe you may also be confused about basic shell operation, like finding executables inside directories listed in `$PATH`. Consider researching the topic, `PATH` is even mentioned [on the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Here is bash documentation on the topic https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution, it's very similar in other shells.

Comment: @MikhailGaponov, nobody claimed that the symlinks were in the `/` directory, so I don't know why bringing that up is supposed to be meaningful here. All that matters is that they get created _in some location listed in the `PATH`_. Alpine creates them in `/bin`. You can do the same thing on portainer, or you can create them anywhere else you choose and add that location to the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

`ln -s /bin/busybox /bin/ash`

if ls works after executing ash, then do
`ln -s /bin/busybox /bin/sh`

I assume busybox is in `/bin` but it may be `/sbin` (depending on distribution decisions) as well.